# The access rules for wizards doesn't works in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I define access rules, that don't permit read. But it remained readable! So object-level permissions don't work for Transient Model?

Comment: Context is important. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again

Answer (score 0):

in Odoo, ACLs only apply to regular models and don't need to be defined for *Abstract* or *Transient* models, if defined, these will be disregarded and a warning message will be triggered into the server log.